# Applying a constraint over one of values of a dictionary in pulp

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, mathematical-optimization, pulp

I need to apply a constraint on the value part of one of my dictionary, I using Pulp for an optimization problem.
I have a food data which has food item info along with their nutritional info and per/serving cost.

My code is working fine giving me the servings of each food and minimized cost. I need to apply a filter with each food items quantity that n is the number in which a particular food item is to be consumed.

[Data reference](https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-programming-and-discrete-optimization-with-python-using-pulp-449f3c5f6e99)

```
from pulp import *
import pandas as pd
prob = LpProblem("Simple Diet Problem", LpMinimize)
df = pd.read_excel("diet - medium.xls", nrows=17)
food_items = list(df['Foods'])
costs = dict(zip(food_items, df['Price/Serving']))
calories = dict(zip(food_items, df['Calories']))
fat = dict(zip(food_items, df['Total_Fat (g)']))
carbs = dict(zip(food_items, df['Carbohydrates (g)']))
food_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Food", food_items, lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')

prob += lpSum([costs[i] * food_vars[i] for i in food_items])
prob += lpSum([calories[f] * food_vars[f] for f in food_items]) >= 800.0
prob += lpSum([calories[f] * food_vars[f] for f in food_items]) <= 1300.0

# Need to apply constraint for number of each items to be consumed

prob.solve()
print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])
for v in prob.variables():
    if v.varValue > 0:
        print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
obj = value(prob.objective)
print("The total cost of this balanced diet is: ${}".format(round(obj, 2)))
```

Comment: Can you clarify "I need to apply a filter with each food items quantity that n is the number in which a particular food item is to be consumed."? I don't understand this. Do you mean that you want to add a constraint saying that the number of items produced of each food has to be >= or <= some number?

Comment: Yes..the corresponding restriction..that a particular food item shouldn't increase its maximum quantity which is stored in my data csv..this would have been easier to apply with lesser number of data..by defining 0<=x1<=n, but how should i do it for huge data set? As of now i have created a for loop in which im restricting the value of each element by keeping it lesser than my stored value..but it is not working as expected

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

1. Create a list of the column headers - all the factors you will use to create the constraints:

   ```
   factors = []
   for col in data.columns:
       factors.append(col)
   ```
2. You will then create your dictionary of dictionaries, where each factor is a key, with a nested dict of food item and the corresponding amounts

   ```
   my_dict = {}

   for i,j in enumerate(factors):
       my_dict[j] = {x[0]: x[i+1] for x in data_list}
   ```

   Be careful here with your slices; make sure you understand which columns are the row names, vs the start of the data.
3. Create a dict with the mins and maxes; here is my example:

   ```
   constraints = pd.read_excel("diet_large.xls")
   constraints = constraints[7147:7149]
   constraints = constraints.values.tolist()
   mins = constraints[0][1:]
   maxs = constraints[1][1:]
   min_dict = dict(zip(factors, mins))
   max_dict = dict(zip(factors, maxs))
   ```
4. Lastly, you will set up your objective function and the constraint functions. Below I am just posting the constraints:

   ```
   for i in factors:
           prob += lpSum([my_dict[i][b] * amountVars[b] for b in food]) >= min_dict[i], ""
           prob += lpSum([my_dict[i][b] * amountVars[b] for b in food]) <= max_dict[i], ""
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you are asking how to add constraints in a loop, rather than one by one. If so, the general approach is like this:

```
for f in food_items:
    prob += food_vars[f] <= max_qty[f]
```

where `max_qty[f]` is the maximum allowable quantity of food `f`, as read from your csv file.